# What does the revert button do on partition screen of the Ubuntu installer?

Tags: 20.04

What does the revert button do on the manage partition screen of the Ubuntu installer?  I selected the Ubuntu main partition and clicked the Revert button a few times.  Does clicking the Revert button do anything?  I am using a pc with a dual-boot configuration of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.  I updated Ubuntu and then updated Windows 10 and lost the ability of selecting Ubuntu from the boot menu.  Now, I do not know if I hurt the SSD because I clicked the Revert button.  I can't find anything about the Revert button.

Answer (score 0):

Because you updated `Windows` after `Ubuntu`, the `Windows Chainloader` (bootmanager) took over again. This will happen after a major `Windows-update` too. Depending on your motherboard/laptop there is a Fsomething function to select your Operating System. For example I have a HP Envy laptop and my button is F11.
 If that doesn't work, enter your UEFI/BIOS and select the USB as first boot device. Plug in your USB-stick with the Ubuntu installer on it and reinstall `Grub2` using the `Terminal` in the live environment. Open the `Terminal` and type `sudo apt install grub`. After that shut down your system, remove USB-stick, restart, and you should see the `Grub-menu` again.

Comment: Before seeing your answer, I did get the boot menu to appear again using information from an online article about boot-repair utility at help.ubuntu dot com.  Your single line command looks easier.